# VSCode how to end a multicommand with previous state restoration

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a `multiCommand` setting thus: in `settings.json`

```
"command": "multiCommand.gotoDebuggerExecutionPoint",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.debug.action.focusCallStackView",
            "list.clear",
            "list.focusFirst",
            "list.select",
            "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
        ]
```

Then, in `keybindings.json` I have

```
{
    "key": "alt+numpad_multiply",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute" , 
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.gotoDebuggerExecutionPoint" }
}
```

So, like `Visual Studio`, `Alt*` gets me to the current execution point while debugging, wherever else I may be in the project.

However, if the sidebar was previously visible, I want it to conitnue to remain visible. If the sidebar was previously hidden (contracted), I want it to continue to remain hidden (contracted). The `multiCommand` sequence above **always** hides the sidebar after execution. This is because the top element in the callstack (which is part of the debug sidebar) get selected making the entire sidebar active regardless of the previous state of the sidebar (visible or hidden).

Is there a way to capture the previous "state" of the sidebar (hidden or visible) and then restore this stage at the end of the `multiCommand`?

Comment: Solution to this was provided here: https://github.com/ryuta46/vscode-multi-command/issues/25